# Why photographing airports is banned if everything is perfectly pictured in Google Maps?

Tags: airport, regulations, security

While staying at Premier Inn, next to [Abu Dhabi International Airport (AUH/OMAA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abu_Dhabi_International_Airport), I was more than surprised to find out warning signs that I'm strictly prohibited from taking photos of the nearby airport form the hotel's roof pool.

Can someone explain me, why such regulations are still in place or how do they aid to airport security, if everything (what I'm banned from photographing from this distance) is perfectly pictured, in a far better details, in Google Maps?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is better asked on Travel.SE.  It has little to do with aviation (the same is true of oil refineries for example) and much to do with culture and history.

Comment: If you're so certain that this fits better for Travel.SE then why you don't flag it for a migration instead of closing? This is the second time this happens to me on this site. A bit weird. I was told that migration is far better across SE than closing questions and asking them again on the other site.

Comment: BTW: I'm completely lost, what -- in your opinion -- question about security and regulations has to do with culture or history? Did you make some strange copy-paste from another question?

Comment: This would almost certainly be off-topic on Travel. Why are such regulations in place? Because the government decided, if it's the law, or the hotel decided, if it's their policy. We don't know why the government or hotel decided to do such an illogical thing. (Well, it might make sense for the hotel: a crowd of people with cameras around the pool might be off-putting for people who want to use the pool. But that would be pure speculation.)

Comment: I wouldn't want to put words into @Simon 's mouth but it's a cultural question because some jurisdictions choose to prohibit taking photos of planes and airports, whereas others have no problem with it. Some cultures are fine with people taking photographs of publicly visible things; others view it as some kind of problem.

Comment: I can't flag for migration, otherwise I would. In my opinion, having travelled a lot, there are many countries where I would happily take a photo of an airport and others were I know I risk jail time. Therefore, in my opinion, it is related to culture, and not to aviation.  Put it this way, to my (uncertain) knowledge there are no regulations in aviation that cover this. All of this said, my opinion doesn't matter. That's why we have a voting system. I have no clue what you imply by "copy/paste".

Comment: @Simon You can use a custom flag to suggest that the moderators migrate the question. (But, as I said, I believe this is off-topic on Travel so please don't, in this case.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about why some cultures choose to restrict photography of locations that they wish to keep secure (e.g., airports, ports, government buildings). There most likely isn't an objective reason.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I disagree.  I can't see why this is off-topic for Travel but I won't use a custom flag.  In my opinion, the lack of a community driven migration vote is a weakness which should not require moderator attention.

Comment: @Simon You won't bother moderator to do something for you, which you can't do because there is no proper functionality? Then for what moderators are in your opinion? Sorry, can't see much sense in your statement. I have just _kindly_ asked a moderator to _consider_ suggested migration. I don't think they should be offended with such (t)ask.

Comment: @Simon It's been my experience as a regular user of Travel questions along the lines of "Why is X illegal in country Y?" and "Why does company C have policy P?" are held to be off-topic since, in general, there's no single objective reason and, especially in the case of company policies, the actual reasons are usually not known to the public. As for not wanting to flag, flags are precisely for drawing the moderators' attention to things that only they can do.

Comment: @DavidRicherby OK, so is there a Stack that would welcome it?

Comment: @Simon I'm not aware of any. (Sorry -- would have saved time if I'd said that earlier.)

Comment: just a comment from a prior military guy who was briefly assigned to a security unit (but far from an expert): google maps does not have "the same stuff in better detail" than the photo you would take. Gmaps is dated, and does not show what equipment is currently where, which is why photo-recon is used just prior to an attack. Granted, anyone planning an attack is not going to be deterred by signage, and will be more stealthy than just standing at the fence line... but that is a big reason for prohibiting photography.

Comment: @FreeMan this question is specific to Abu Dhabi, the FAA and DHS have no authority there.

Comment: Google didn't ask permission when they used satellite and overflight data. They will blur on request however.  The same thing for non-public streets driven by streetview drivers.

Comment: @Jimmy Your comment sounds like a good explanation and answer.

Comment: @FreeMan That's... **AUH**, not _DUH_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the sign is to prevent plane watchers from gathering at the spot and taking pictures of every aircraft taking off or landing, which, judging by the existence of the sign, is not how the location is intended to be used.

Comment: It's much more than that.  In most of the Middle East, it is illegal to photograph any area, building or facility considered of military importance or having a high security risk.  Those no photography signs are enforceable.

Comment: @Simon not just in the Middle East, in most of the world. This went so far in the USSR we were told to not take photos inside the cabin of civilian airliners because we might inadvertently capture a glimpse of some equipment or (through the window) a postage stamp sized image of a military base 10km below us. At the time, even photographing road bridges and policeman directing traffic at intersections was illegal there.

Comment: If you go to plane watching sites there's a lot of discussion about US airports that have problems with photography. Although there are no laws about it that I know of, airports are generally private property and airport security often has a pickle in their butts about people standing at the fence with a camera.

Comment: My question and this answer brought so much attention and so many valuable, pure-aviation comments, that I still don't get it, how or why this question is off-topic here.